# Creating Intranet site with windows auth that checks users cross-domain does not let me through after giving credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-domain, windows-authentication

I'm trying to create an intranet site that will use windows auth for users but the site is going to be hosted in a server in DOMAINB, but the users are logged into DOMAINA.

In IIS I have windows auth enabled.

When I go to the site, it prompts me for a username and password, I give it my username and password to DOMAINA (which I'm already logged into from the computer I'm testing with) but doesn't let me through and just asks me again.

This is what my config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringDOMAINA" connectionString="LDAP://DOMAINA ACTIVE DIRECTORY SERVER ADDRESS:3268"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="DOMAINAProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ConnectionStringDOMAINA"
             connectionUsername="DOMAINA\service account username"
             connectionPassword="service account password"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers><remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" /><remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /><remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone think of what I could be missing? This is the first time I've had to deal with a windows auth site that checks across domains, so I'm sure its something simple and stupid.

**Update:** Yes, the server DOES have access to the domain control server, I can telnet to it using ports 389 and 3268.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a good starting point for you:

If you have a properly configured a trust relationship between two domains you can assign permissions for DomainA\UserName on a server/resource in DomainB

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977993.aspx